# How can I implement a sliding title in Uinavigation Bar in ios swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

My requirement is that the title of the navigation bar must slide from left to right. How can I do this type of animations? I am using storyboard for my app development.
Thanks!

Comment: please be more specific, so you want to be able to swipe the title to have another text, or you want that when your view appears the title animate from left to right  ?

Comment: Sorry for not being specific. Basically, as soon as my home page appears the nav bar title will be shown dynamically and title will keep on animating from left to right always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom `UILabel` as a `titleView`  and then animate it in `viewDidAppear` your code should looks like (code tested)

```
 override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    /* Create custom label as titleView of the navigation controller */
    let titleLabel  = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50))
    titleLabel.text =  "My Title"
    self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel

    /* Animate the label */
    let moveAnimation = CATransition()
    moveAnimation.duration = 0.5
    moveAnimation.type = kCATransitionPush
    titleLabel.layer.addAnimation(moveAnimation, forKey:"moveText")
}
```